# Не получается получить ответ с сайта

Tags: java, android, json

Пытаюсь через приложение создать запись в базу данных сайта.
После того как я в приложении ввожу данные(имя, фамилия, пароль, емайл) и нажимаю кнопку, которая запускает этот процесс - приложение вылетает.
LogCat:

```
09-12 18:56:56.981: ERROR/Buffer Error(2343): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
09-12 18:56:57.058: ERROR/JSON Parser(2343): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
09-12 18:56:57.358: WARN/dalvikvm(2343): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
09-12 18:56:57.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2343): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
09-12 18:56:57.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2343): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-12 18:56:57.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2343):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
09-12 18:56:57.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2343):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
09-12 18:56:57.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2343):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
09-12 18:56:57.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2343):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
09-12 18:56:57.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2343):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
09-12 18:56:57.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2343):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
09-12 18:56:57.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2343):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
09-12 18:56:57.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2343):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
09-12 18:56:57.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2343): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-12 18:56:57.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2343):     at ru.mystory.text.Regictration$RegNewUser.doInBackground(Regictration.java:106)
09-12 18:56:57.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2343):     at ru.mystory.text.Regictration$RegNewUser.doInBackground(Regictration.java:1)
09-12 18:56:57.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2343):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
09-12 18:56:57.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2343):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
09-12 18:56:57.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2343):     ... 4 more
```

Код Activity:

```
public class Regictration extends Activity {

EditText nameReg, familReg, elMailReg, passWordReg;

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
private static String url_registration = "http://site.ru/reg.php";
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.regictration);



    nameReg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    familReg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.famil);
    elMailReg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.elMail);
    passWordReg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passWord);

    Button btnRegOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonReg);

    btnRegOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new RegNewUser().execute();
        }
    });


}


class RegNewUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Regictration.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Создание продукта...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
        System.out.println("Начало регистрации");
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String[] args) {
        String name = nameReg.getText().toString();
        String famil = familReg.getText().toString();
        String email = elMailReg.getText().toString();
        String password = passWordReg.getText().toString();

        // Заполняем параметры
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("famil", famil));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

        // получаем JSON объект
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_registration, "POST", params);

        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {

                System.out.println("Зарегистрирован");

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        System.out.println("Конец");
    }



}

}
```

Код php обработчика:

```
<?php
$response = array();

if (isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['famil'])) {
require 'db_connect.php';
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

$name =  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$password = md5(md5(trim($_POST['password'])));
$famil =  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['famil']);

$zapros = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(name, password, famil) VALUES('$name', '$password', '$famil')");

if ($zapros) {
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Okay!";

    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Errors!";

    echo json_encode($response);
}

} else {
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Error! Zapolneni ne vse polya";

echo json_encode($response);
}

?>
```

В браузере ответ получается такой:

```
{"success":0,"message":"Error! Zapolneni ne vse polya"}
```

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое что бросается в глаза это вот эти строчки в `doInBackground()`

> ```
> String name = nameReg.getText().toString();
> String famil = familReg.getText().toString();
> String email = elMailReg.getText().toString();
> String password = passWordReg.getText().toString();
> ```

Есть такое строгое **правило** - нельзя обращаться к элементам UI(user interface) не из UI-потока.

Следовательно значения этих EditText надо извлечь перед запуском AsyncTask и передать как параметры например, либо же получить в методе `onPreExecute()`, в котором еще можно работать с элементами UI.